# How to create for Loop (issue)?

Tags: python

I have an issue. I am not sure how to create a loop for my code. I tried to use "for labele in labeles" but it doesn't work. The part of my code is here.

```
points_of_cluster_0 = X[labels==0,:]
centroid_of_cluster_0 = np.mean(points_of_cluster_0, axis=0) 
print(centroid_of_cluster_0)

points_of_cluster_1 = X[labels==1,:]
centroid_of_cluster_1 = np.mean(points_of_cluster_1, axis=0)
print(centroid_of_cluster_1)

points_of_cluster_2 = X[labels==2,:]
centroid_of_cluster_2 = np.mean(points_of_cluster_2, axis=0)
print(centroid_of_cluster_2)

points_of_cluster_3 = X[labels==3,:]
centroid_of_cluster_3 = np.mean(points_of_cluster_3, axis=0)
print(centroid_of_cluster_3)

points_of_cluster_4 = X[labels==4,:]
centroid_of_cluster_4 = np.mean(points_of_cluster_4, axis=0)
print(centroid_of_cluster_4)

points_of_cluster_5 = X[labels==5,:]
centroid_of_cluster_5 = np.mean(points_of_cluster_5, axis=0)
print(centroid_of_cluster_5)

points_of_cluster_6 = X[labels==6,:]
centroid_of_cluster_6 = np.mean(points_of_cluster_6, axis=0)
print(centroid_of_cluster_6)

points_of_cluster_7 = X[labels==7,:]
centroid_of_cluster_7 = np.mean(points_of_cluster_7, axis=0)
print(centroid_of_cluster_7)

points_of_cluster_8 = X[labels==8,:]
centroid_of_cluster_8 = np.mean(points_of_cluster_8, axis=0)
print(centroid_of_cluster_8)
```

Comment: please provide more information, what is expetced and what have you tried so far ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a simple loop:

```
number_of_labels = 9
for i in range(number_of_labels):
    points_of_cluster = X[labels==i,:]
    centroid_of_cluster = np.mean(points_of_cluster, axis=0)
    print(centroid_of_cluster)
```